# Proof that ${n\choose r}$ always yields a natural number proof by induction

Tags: calculus, induction, proof-explanation

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfy4d.jpg)
Hi I'm trying to prove that the ${n\choose r}$ formula gives a natural number by using proof by induction and I'm stuck on the last stage (in the picture above). Have I messed up earlier on and if not then how can I show that $\frac{n+1}{n-r+1}$ is a natural number. I know there are other articles in the stack exchange but I can't seem to find an answer to this.
Cheers

Comment: There's no guarantee that $\frac{n+1}{n-r+1}$ will be a natural number, e.g., $n=3, r=1$.

Comment: So what have I done wrong?

Comment: This proof primarily relies on Pascal's Triangle Identity ; ${n+1\choose k+1} = {n\choose k+1}  + {n\choose k} $

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this falls under category of "induction", but if you knew about Pascal's triangle you could guess the following:

$$
{n\choose r}+{n\choose r+1}={n+1\choose r+1}
$$

this can be verified by algebraic computation, and you only need to worry about cases when $r=0$ or $r=n+1$, which are simple enough to directly compute ($=1$)

rest of the terms are guranteed to be integers assuming the result for $n$

Comment: I hope you are saying $\displaystyle {n+1 \choose 0}={n+1 \choose n+1}=1$ or more simply $\displaystyle {n \choose 0}={n \choose n}=1$

Comment: @Henry I was under assumption that I was refering to ${n+1 \choose r}$ for some reason